# How to restore keyWindow (NSView - Appkit)

Tags: objective-c, nsview, appkit, keywindow

I have some code which opens a modal window (itself composed from a few views) and makes it closed when we click anywhere on it.

here is some part of code:

```
int myFunc()
{
    // Create views
    NSPanel *panel =  ...;

    CustomNSTextView * textView = ... ;
    CustomNSImageView * imageView = ...;

    [view addSubview:textView];
    [view addSubview:imageView];
    [panel setContentView:view];

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:panel];

    NSView* parentView = [view superview];
    [[parentView window] makeFirstResponder:parentView];


    [textView release];
    [imageView release];
    [view release];
    [panel release];
}

@implementation CustomNSTextView : NSTextView

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
#pragma unused(theEvent)
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
}

@implementation CustomNSImageView : NSImageView

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
#pragma unused(theEvent)
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
}
```

The bug is after the window is closed, the application (that launched the modal window), won't receive any key event anymore (while it still was as the modal window was still open).
Only after I refocus on the application, it will receive key events again.

Please anyone gives me some idea, I could not find something relevant on the net.

Thanks
Nathaniel

Comment: Is `parentView` nil? And if not, don't make the panel first responder.

Comment: no, parentView is not nil. I don't get the advise, what means "don't make the panel first responder". What makes you say it is?

Comment: `[[parentView window] makeFirstResponder:parentView];` tries to make a view of the panel first responder.

Comment: Really? Why? Isn't parentView supposed to be the window inside which was panel created?

Comment: No, `parentView` is the superview of `view` and is in the same window = the panel.